# python: open two files as one fileobject

Tags: python

I have two files: a header and the body. I am *using a library* to read the whole thing. I can use "fileinput.input" to create one FileInput object and hand this to the library that reads the data. Problem is FileInput objects do not have a '.read' attribute which the library seems to expect.

I need a FileObject with a .read that is like reading both files as one.

Any ideas existing workarounds? Yes, I know I can build my own little class or cat files together. Just wondering if there is some magic FileObject joiner I've never heard of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your library reads from a file with `.read()`, there isn't much point in some abstraction of merging multiple file-objects as one. it is quite trivial to read everything and throw it into `StringIO`.

Comment: I guess the only problem is if you have a header file with 3 lines and then a large number of lines. I think StringIO could be memory heavy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to call readline() on the files, try this:

```
def cat(*args):
    for arg in args:
        with open(arg,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line

for line in cat('/tmp/x1','/tmp/x2'):
    processLine(line)
```

Comment: I guess what I want is a file object that is indistinguishable from catting the files together and then opening the combined file. Using a tmp file is fine, but I was wondering if there was some magic joiner in python.

Answer (score 1):

Your file objects are already iterable via generators, so just use itertools to chain them into one big iterable.

```
import itertools
all_the_things = itertools.chain(HeaderFile, BodyFile)
for line in all_the_things:
   # your code here
```

Comment: This doesn't work. all_the_things.read does not exist. Yes, using .read is not great but I don't get to change the library I'm using, that's the game.